# Extract element content as list and exclude sub element with XPath 1.0

Tags: xpath, xpath-1.0

I am currently trying to extract the `li` strings als element list, but I 
want to exclude the `form` element

What I achieved so far is not returning two items because of the `a` elements in between

`//*[@id="quickPromoBucketContent"]//li[descendant::form]/text()`

HTML:

```
<div class="bucket" id="quickPromoBucketContent">
 <div class="content">
  <ul class="qpUL">
  <li>Sparen Sie 5&nbsp;% beim Kauf von <a href="">Wasserdichte Handyhülle 2 Stück</a> wenn Sie 1 oder mehrere Auto Handy Halterung aus dem Angebot von UGREEN GROUP LIMITED UK
    erwerben! Geben Sie den Code 49DFYWAQ an der Kasse ein. <a href="" target="AmazonHelp">Weitere Informationen</a>        (Teilnahmebedingungen)
    <form method="post" action="/gp/item-dispatch">
    </form>
  </li>
  <li>Sparen Sie 5&nbsp;% beim Kauf von <a href="">USB C PD Schnellladekabel</a> wenn Sie 1 oder mehrere Auto Handyhalterung aus dem Angebot von UGREEN GROUP LIMITED UK erwerben!
    Geben Sie den Code 5BWVW4YN an der Kasse ein. <a href="" target="AmazonHelp">Weitere Informationen</a>        (Teilnahmebedingungen)
    <form method="post" action="/gp/item-dispatch">
    </form>
  </li>
  <li><span id="productPromotion_clipped"><span>Aktivieren Sie diesen Coupon</span>, um beim Kauf dieses Produkts bei Amazon.de 10&nbsp;% zu sparen.</span>
  </li><input type="hidden" name="specialOffersHidden" id="specialOffersHidden">
  <li>
    <div class="amabot_widget">
    </div>
  </li>
 </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want to those `li`s that have a descendant `form` - or only include those that have one? Please clarify.

Comment: I only want to include the ones that have one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guessing from your sample code you want to query

- all li elements below and element with the attribute `id="quickPromoBucketContent"`
- that have a form descendant
- get the text of all child/descendant nodes from there

Try it like this:

```
//*[@id="quickPromoBucketContent"]//li[descendant::form]/descendant-or-self::*/text()
```

**[XPath Demo](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/xidelcgi?&data=%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22bucket%22%20id%3D%22quickPromoBucketContent%22%3E%0A%20%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22content%22%3E%0A%20%20%3Cul%20class%3D%22qpUL%22%3E%0A%20%20%3Cli%3ESparen%20Sie%205%26nbsp%3B%25%20beim%20Kauf%20von%20%3Ca%20href%3D%22%22%3EWasserdichte%20Handyh%C3%83%C2%BClle%202%20St%C3%83%C2%BCck%3C%2Fa%3E%20wenn%20Sie%201%20oder%20mehrere%20Auto%20Handy%20Halterung%20aus%20dem%20Angebot%20von%20UGREEN%20GROUP%20LIMITED%20UK%0A%20%20%20%20erwerben!%20Geben%20Sie%20den%20Code%2049DFYWAQ%20an%20der%20Kasse%20ein.%20%3Ca%20href%3D%22%22%20target%3D%22AmazonHelp%22%3EWeitere%20Informationen%3C%2Fa%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20(Teilnahmebedingungen)%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cform%20method%3D%22post%22%20action%3D%22%2Fgp%2Fitem-dispatch%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fform%3E%0A%20%20%3C%2Fli%3E%0A%20%20%3Cli%3ESparen%20Sie%205%26nbsp%3B%25%20beim%20Kauf%20von%20%3Ca%20href%3D%22%22%3EUSB%20C%20PD%20Schnellladekabel%3C%2Fa%3E%20wenn%20Sie%201%20oder%20mehrere%20Auto%20Handyhalterung%20aus%20dem%20Angebot%20von%20UGREEN%20GROUP%20LIMITED%20UK%20erwerben!%0A%20%20%20%20Geben%20Sie%20den%20Code%205BWVW4YN%20an%20der%20Kasse%20ein.%20%3Ca%20href%3D%22%22%20target%3D%22AmazonHelp%22%3EWeitere%20Informationen%3C%2Fa%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20(Teilnahmebedingungen)%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cform%20method%3D%22post%22%20action%3D%22%2Fgp%2Fitem-dispatch%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fform%3E%0A%20%20%3C%2Fli%3E%0A%20%20%3Cli%3E%3Cspan%20id%3D%22productPromotion_clipped%22%3E%3Cspan%3EAktivieren%20Sie%20diesen%20Coupon%3C%2Fspan%3E%2C%20um%20beim%20Kauf%20dieses%20Produkts%20bei%20Amazon.de%2010%26nbsp%3B%25%20zu%20sparen.%3C%2Fspan%3E%0A%20%20%3C%2Fli%3E%3Cinput%20type%3D%22hidden%22%20name%3D%22specialOffersHidden%22%20id%3D%22specialOffersHidden%22%3E%0A%20%20%3Cli%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22amabot_widget%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0A%20%20%3C%2Fli%3E%0A%20%3C%2Ful%3E%0A%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0A%3C%2Fdiv%3E&=&extract=%2F%2F*%5B%40id%3D%22quickPromoBucketContent%22%5D%2F%2Fli%5Bdescendant%3A%3Aform%5D%2Fdescendant-or-self%3A%3A*%2Ftext()&=%2F%2F*%5B%40id%3D%22quickPromoBucketContent%22%5D%2F%2Fli%5Bdescendant%3A%3Aform%5D%2Fdescendant-or-self%3A%3A*%2Ftext()&input-format=auto&printed-node-format=html&output-format=adhoc&compatibility=Enable%20all%20extensions&dot-notation=unambiguous&extract-kind=xpath2)**

Comment: The `descendant-or-self::*` and `descendant::` are a little verbose. You could shorten it to `//*[@id="quickPromoBucketContent"]//li[.//form]//text()`

Comment: Also, the OP said "_but I want to exclude the form element_" so I think you'd need to add a predicate to `text()`. Example: `//*[@id="quickPromoBucketContent"]//li[.//form]//text()[not(ancestor::form)]`

Comment: @DanielHaley Thanks. Yes, the query can be shortened. However, I interpret the remark about the form elements differently. The OP is not 100% clear in that respect.

Comment: Thank you, this is working. @DanielHaley can you explain whats the difference?
I forgot: I also want to exclude all elements that have `target="AmazonHelp"`

Comment: `//*[@id="quickPromoBucketContent"]//li[.//form]//text()[not(ancestor::form) and not(ancestor::a[@target, "AmazonHelp"])]` would be the way, is there also a possibility to exclude everything behind the `<a>` even though its part of the `li` element?